Spyder stack frame file paths font too dark
I am using Spyder, installed via Anaconda on Windows 10.
When there is an error, the stack trace show all but the bottommost stack frame with the *.py file path in dark green font and black background.  I like everything else about the colour scheme, so I don't want to change schemes.  I can't find my way to a preference control for changing the font colour.
Is there a way to control this specific colour?
I find myself highlighting the stacktrace just to be able to see the text for the file paths.  I would like to avoid this in the debugging process.
